# Building a factor variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset (named `wash`) that describes murders over several years in Washington State. There are variables for `Victim.Sex` and `Perpetrator.Sex`. Right now I am trying to build a scatterplot of victim age vs. perpetrator age, and I'd like to place 4 loess lines through it (each line representing a different victim/perpetrator sex combination). I am trying to learn dplyr so I tried using mutate, below:

```
`wash %>%
   mutate(mvic_mperp = (Victim.Sex == "Male" & Perpetrator.Sex == "Male") %>%
   mutate(mvic_fperp = (Victim.Sex == "Male" & Perpetrator.Sex == "Female") %>%
   mutate(fvic_mperp = (Victim.Sex == "Female" & Perpetrator.Sex == "Male") %>%
   mutate(fvic_fperp = (Victim.Sex == "Female" & Perpetrator.Sex == "Female") %>%`
```

I know this creates a specific variable that corresponds to each combination of victim/perpetrator sex, but (1) I am unsure of the next step needed to combine them all, and (2) I'm sure there is an easier way of doing this using `factor()` but I am unsure of how to proceed. Thanks in advance, I'm quite new to R and most programming in general so I am still struggling with the basics.

Edit: To be clear, I am trying to build a factor variable to insert into a geom_point(), not looking specifically how to build the scatterplot itself.

Comment: how about `as.factor(paste(Victim.Sex, Perpetrator.sex))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to begin by synthesizing some data since you didn't provide any.  This will just be a random sample.

```
df <- data.frame(Perpetrator.Sex = sample(c("M","F"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                 Victim.Sex = sample(c("M","F"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                 Perpetrator.Age = rnorm(50, mean=40, sd =10),
                 Victim.Age = rnorm(50, mean=40, sd =10))
```

We actually don't have to do any transformations on the data itself.  Since you want to use `ggplot2`, the `Perpetrator.Sex`/`Victim.Sex` interactions can be attained using the `interaction` function.  To just make a scatter plot of the ages colored by `Perpetrator.Sex`/`Victim.Sex` you can use:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Perpetrator.Age, Victim.Age)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color = interaction(Perpetrator.Sex, Victim.Sex)))
p
```

[image: Scatterplot, no lines]

To add the regression lines, you can use `geom_smooth`.

```
p + geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x, 
                aes(color = interaction(Perpetrator.Sex, Victim.Sex)))
```

[image: plot with regression lines]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. As a follow-up question, there are some values labeled as `Unknown` in `Perpetrator.Sex` and `Victim.Sex`. I'd like to remove these for purposes of this scatterplot. I tried doing so with the following: `wash %>%
  filter(Perpetrator.Sex = "Male" | Perpetrator.Sex = "Female") %>% filter(Victim.Sex = "Male" | Victim.Sex = "Female") %>%
ggplot(wash, aes(Perpetrator.Age, Victim.Age)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = interaction(Perpetrator.Sex, Victim.Sex)), alpha = 0.3) `  The plot still displays points for which sex is unknown.

Comment: I think your problem is your are passing `wash` to ggplot rather than letting the output of the pipe be the first input, but I don't use `dplyr` much so I am not sure.  You can also directly us `wash[Perpetrator.Sex != "Unknown" & Victim.Sex != "Unknown", ]`.